# How to extract the fixed size ROI for multiple images?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, contour

I have a folder of images. I would like to extract the object as fixed size ROI such as (100*100) and extract the location of that object. I use the following code. But it can only crop the contours into various rectangle shape. My target is to extract the object into equal size frame. I need like the following samples where the output patch are equal shape.
[image: input output samples]

```
        import cv2
        import glob


        def crop_brain_contour(image):
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # grayscale
            cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

            #ROI_number = 0
            for c in cnts:
               x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
               ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
               #cv2.imwrite('ROI_{}.png'.format(ROI_number), ROI)
               #ROI_number += 1
               return ROI

        i=0
        for img in glob.glob('./image_data/*.bmp'):
           cv_img = cv2.imread(img)
           img_crop = crop_brain_contour(cv_img)
           #img_resize = cv2.resize(img_crop,(224,224))
           cv2.imwrite("./extracted_data_1/image%04i.bmp" %i,img_crop)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I need to fixed the shape for all images." Maybe reframe the question so that it's more clear to understand what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guidelines.

Comment: I'm not clear what you want with small, medium and large? Do you want 3 output images for each input image? Is the problem that something is square but you want it rectangular?

Comment: sorry for my mistake. Now I make it more clear. Actually, I need one image one output and all output images are same shape/ size for example (100*100). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes where you are calling the crop_brain_contour function:

```
desired_width, desired_height = (100, 100)
final_img = np.zeros((desired_height, desired_width, 3), dtype="uint8")
img_crop = crop_brain_contour(cv_img)
h,w = img_crop.shape[:2]
#Make sure h < desired_height and w < desired_width
x1 = int(desired_width/2 - w/2)
y1 = int(desired_height/2 - h/2)
x2 = x1 + w
y2 = y1 + h

final_img[y1:y2, x1:x2, :] = img_crop

# Write the final image
cv2.imwrite("./extracted_data_1/image%04i.bmp" %i,final_img)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying and inform you.

Comment: tania, were you able to find it working? I have made a change to my answer. Make sure you pass all 3 channels RIO from crop_brain_contour function. Upvote and accept the answer if you found it helpful so that others can find it easily.

Comment: final_img[y1:y2, x1:x2] = img_crop
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (113,77,3) into shape (6,77,3). I got these types of errors.

Comment: Forked, thank you so much. It works and now I would like to extract the location of the object.

Comment: Tania, what do you mean by the location of the object? Object location relative to the original image is already extracted by x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c). You can return that information back to your calling code using tuples, for eg. return (ROI, (x,y,w,h))

Comment: oooooo,,,,I understand. Thank you so much.